Modify session nls value for a query
I use spring boot with spring data jpa.
In my properties file i have
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-init-sql

I search a way to modify this value temporaray for one jpa query then i call from a spring data repository
Edit
i tried without success
@Transactional
public List<String> findJob() {

        jobRepository.setSessionCaseSensitive();

        Set<String> setJob = new HashSet<>();
        setJob.addAll(jobRepository.findJobEmployee();
        jobRepository.setSessionCaseInSensitive();
        setPerson.removeIf(Objects::isNull);

        return new ArrayList<>(setPerson);
}

In my repository for
@Query(value = "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT='binary'",  nativeQuery = true)
@Modifying
void setSessionCaseSensitive();

Edit 2
query log is enable, i see findJobEmployee query in the log, but not the one for setSessionCaseSensitive and setSessionCaseInSensitive

You can always create an implementation of your repository (assuming you are using the default interface approach) and add the set nls there before and after your query. Other approach would be to use a procedure to do so, set nls, run the query, reset nls return the cursor/rows. I'm not sure if there is a way through configuration to do that, those are the ones I know you can do.

Another one is depending where you are controlling your transaction (@Trasactional annotation) you can move it on level up, call the set nls, your query, reset nls.

created a transaction, done the set before the query, done the query, reset... and get same result

I don't think you can do a @Modifying query in a readOnly transaction try without the readOnly.

removed the read only, same result

huh... is your repository class also annotated with transaction? If that is not the case. I'm out of options on that front, the other thing you might be able to use is to change the query itself to use the NLSSORT function something like order by NLSSORT(yourColumn, 'NLS_SORT=BINARY')

Or
ORDER BY colname collate [binary_ci|binary_ai]
binary_ci being accent-sensitive and case-insensitive, binary_ai being accent-insensitive and case-insensitive
